# How do I pass node args when using pm2 on windows

Tags: node.js, pm2

This is the `pm2 start` that works fine on ubuntu. But the node-args are not being passed the same way on windows. So how do I go about doing that?

```
pm2 start --node-args="--experimental-modules" app.js
```

This is the error I get

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader

I realise I can use the config file but I am looking for a way to do it form the cli itself like it works in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments as below

```
pm2 start app.js --node-args="--production --port=1337"
```